# Android: How do I get the Settings menu to appear with NavigationUI?

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferences, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to follow this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui along with a review of https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#8 (although the second link is in Kotlin and I'm coding in Javascript) to implement an App in Android with navigation drawer on the left and a settings button (preferences) on the top right.

I'm using the NavigationUI with fragments for each option from the drawer and the settings.

My problem is that my settings fragment is not appearing. I think I'm nearly there, but despite reviewing several articles and questions cannot get it to work.

This code allows me to switch fragment from the nav drawer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    //NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
}
```

If I switch the commented code on the last two lines (so I execute the last line but not second to last), to match the guide then the switching of fragment fails.

My code to handle the Settings menu is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
/*
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        // TODO: Do something to accept settings
        View contextView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); // Apparently any layout can be used
        Snackbar.make(contextView, "Settings", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        //changeFragment(new SettingsFragment());
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new SettingsFragment(), "nh")
                .addToBackStack("nh")
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
*/
}
```

The active portion matches the guide above, is getting called (proved by setting a breakpoint) but doing nothing.

If I alternatively switch this for the commented out code instead, then my settings fragment does appear but overlays the current fragment. I understand from another answer that this is because I am using two different methods to handle fragment visibility, which makes sense and is why I am trying to get my settings fragment to be handled by the NavigationUI framework.

I feel that it must be quite simple to cure, but having read and re-read the guide (and lots of answers cannot make it work)

Comment: all I understand is that you want Drawer Layout and Menu in your toolbar, Am I right? and you're using preferences to setup settings which you came in from Menu in the toolbar, Right? But your settings don't show up. Right?

Comment: That sounds right - I might have some of my terms wrong as this is my first app.
I have three fragments on the bar that comes in from left (= Drawer Layout?).
I have one settings menu (defined as public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat along with an associated XML file defining the layout of the seetings).
I can't get the settings to show up using NavigationUI.

Comment: well try to add your setting fragment or activity in your navigation component, then after implement menu's onClick, call navigation which you already created in the navigation component. but it's not good practice to have Drawer and Menu together, One of them is necessary. if you setup drawer and menu, it will be Annoying.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should add the Settings menu as another fragment in the drawer? I think you probably are as looking at a few apps on my phone they do have one or the other.

Comment: No, no. Your setting couldn't be in your drawer. Look, setting is a new fragment. So you should navigate from current fragment to the settings fragment. For this action, as you said you're using navigation component, so you should implement the settings fragment in to the navigation component, then in the menu option OR drawer menu, when you click on the settings, you should call navigation action from current fragment to the settings.

Comment: As I can't get the settings fragment to appear properly, I've now created the settings as an activity. I've now got that loading properly but every time I go back from the settings menu, the default start fragment is displayed. That's not the end of the world, but it's not how Android apps are supposed to work. I've tried storing the fragment the app was in, but when the Settings menu goes back it causes the OnCreate method to trigger. I tried saving thefragment in a bundle in onSaveInstanceState, only to discover that onRestoreInstanceState is not called, so it's not restored

Comment: Give me an email, i'll send you a sample. If that's what you need, i'll put it here as an answer. Because im not sure am i giving you the the right thing? Maybe i didn't understand you very well, but if everything is ok, the the solution which i'll send you is the way gonno help you

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I cannot find a way of messaging you - I've researched and there is no direct messaging system here. There is a "chat" facility but you don't seem to be on there. I wonder if you could make the sample available on a public page on something like Dropbox. It wouldn't be good practice to post an e-mail on this public forum (I'll get spammed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I'm not sure if I understand your problem well. But here is my solution and I hope it helps you.

Here is my Navigation Graph
[image]

And this is the Code. As you see I've an action in SettingsFragment:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:name="packageName.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="Settings Fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/actionSettingsToPassword"
        app:destination="@id/passwordDialogFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_open_exit" />
```

And this is my bottomNavigationMenu's XML:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings" />
```

**Remember that the ID in the Navigation & Menu should be the same.** As you see in the codes, the ID of *"Settings Fragment"* is the same:

> ```
>     android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
> ```

I don't know if you know how to add preferences.xml in your resources. Just for sure I write it too:

> Right Click on "res" New > Android Resource Directory

In the Resource Type field, pickup XML. Now you gonna have xml folder under "res". Again:

> Right Click on "xml" New > XML Recourse File

Now, Here is my "preferences.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Weather Location">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:disableDependentsState="true"
        android:key="USE_DEVICE_LOCATION"
        android:summary="Allow The App To Get Your Location"
        android:title="Use Device Location" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Tehran"
        android:dependency="USE_DEVICE_LOCATION"
        android:key="CUSTOM_LOCATION"
        android:summary="The Location For Which The Weather Is Displayed"
        android:title="Location" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Units">
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="METRIC"
        android:entries="@array/unitSystemEntries"
        android:key="UNIT_SYSTEM"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="Unit System"
        android:entryValues="@array/unitSystemValues"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then create a "Kotlin" or "Java" class and set the XML to your class like this **(depend on which language are you writing)**:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = "Settings"
    (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.subtitle = null
}
}
```

And here is my Application Class:

```
class ForecastApplication : Application(){
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false)
}
}
```

and in your application's Manifest, inside the application tag, define the Application class you already created.

```
        android:name=".ForecastApplication"
```

I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: How is your  @layout/fragment_settings related to preferences.xml?
I think it's key that I am missing @layout/fragment_settings, but like you I have a preferences.xml (in the xml resource directory) which defines the view of the settings fragment.

Comment: I already provide you my SettingsFragment too. look at it. and also you should create an application class and set "PreferenceManager" to that class too. I forget to provide that class to you, but I already edited my post and show you my Application class too.

Comment: @PeteC My SettingFragment doesn't have (@layout/fragment_settings). the Layout is (R.xml.preferences) look at SettingsFragment's code. to understand how to set preferences xml

Comment: The first part of your solution (right below the navigation graph) references @layout/fragment_settings, here: <fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:name="packageName.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="Settings Fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">.  (Sorry but the layout doesn't keep the formatting in responses). I agree that the layout is set in R.xml.preferences, which has me wondering what @layout/fragment_settings contains (and may just be the reason that I've failed in the the first place)

Comment: @PeteC ahh. yes, you're right. It's my mistake. I should remove it :-). I already edited code again. just forget the layout. You should set the layout from XML's folder (for example R.xml.preferences). that's all. just don't forget that the ID in the Navigation & Menu should be the same.

Comment: Excellent - that's got it working thanks. Now I just need to figure out why it always goes back to my start fragment rather than the fragment that was visible, but that's a different question and has something to do with the back navigation).

Comment: Yeay... After 1mounth and half. I didn't get what's your problem. Search for it or, if the problem is not already exist, make another topic. have a nice time.

Answer (score 3):

You have different options:

Just define the `SettingsFragment` in your navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--Your fragments-->


    <!--Settings fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name=".SettingsFragment"/>

</navigation>
```

Then inflate your menu with:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

In your menu use the same id used in the graph:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        .../>

</menu>
```

Finally override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

---

You can also define a [Global Action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <!--Global action-->
    <action android:id="@+id/action_global_open_settings_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/settingsFragment"/>

</navigation>
```

Then in your code to navigate to a destination just use:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_global_open_settings_fragment);
```

Comment: I think I already had your option 1 implemented with the exception that I had used  different (but identical) name for @+id/settingsFragment in both places and I have no <menu section. 

I had created my settings menu from File - New - Other - Settings Fragment and it doesn't have <menu ... </menu> in it. I'd added the id to:
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment">
...
</PreferenceScreen>

I have changed the ID to match your suggestion, from nav_settings

Comment: I followed your option 1 exactly, and it works. Thank you for saving me hours of googling.